# local postgres db keeps giving error duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, duplicates

I don't understand why postgres is raising:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint
```

I went to check the table in pgadmin to see if the table really did have a duplicate and see:

Running VACUUM recommended

The estimated rowcount on the table deviates significantly from the actual rowcount.

Why is this happening?  Luckily it doesn't seem to happen in production on heroku.  It's a rails app.

**Update:**

Here is the sql log:

> SQL (2.6ms)  INSERT INTO "favorites" ("artist_id", "author_id",
>   "created_at", "post_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
>   RETURNING "id"  [["artist_id", 17], ["author_id", nil], ["created_at",
>   Sun, 18 Mar 2012 03:48:37 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 62], ["updated_at",
>   Sun, 18 Mar 2012 03:48:37 UTC +00:00]] PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate
>   key value violates unique constraint
>   "index_favorites_on_artist_id_and_post_id" DETAIL:  Key (artist_id,
>   post_id)=(17, 62) already exists.

But in the actual table there is no such record with artist_id = 17 and post_id = 62.  But postgres believes that there is.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about when this error is occurring. Duplicate key violations wouldn't leave a duplicate in the table but it can cause an insert or update to fail.  The vaccume thing is unrelated you should look into auto-vacuum or (depending on version) set a scheduled task to vacuum automatically.

Comment: I updated question with some example.

Comment: Usually you would expect one key to exist afterwords but as sketchfemme indicates in his answer, simultaneous statements may be a problem. OR something attempting to add the same key twice in the same transaction will cause the whole transaction to roll back and neither row will stay in the table.  Is there a reason why post_id is not being assigned by a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i think the problem is not related to postgres at all.  It was a combination of simultaneous duplicate ajax calls creating what would be a duplicate record, then neither are inserted.

Answer (score 9):

You need to run [`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html) to get the row count in sync. In pgAdmin right click the table and choose "Maintenance" for that. Then press `F5` on the table.

Doesn't have anything to do with the unique key violation, though. That means a value you try to enter in a column with a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is already present in another row.

Answer (score 4):

In case of PostgreSQL unique key violation error messages, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')` might help to bring the key back in sync.

Answer (score 2):

A common cause of this is that you've put data into a table with a primary key that's normally provided by a serial type, but the sequence behind the default() isn't in sync with the table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in my **development environment**. This worked for me `phppgadmin->admin->reindex`.
**My solution is dangerous** in some situations as it updates whole database.I suggest to look other solutions as well when working in production environment.
However, `Analyse` is a good way to start as suggested by @Erwin Brandstetter