# Django syncing Database Integrity Error

Tags: django, heroku

i was trying to deploy my application to heroku i was using sqlite so i have changed the settings to postgreSQL, i had some initial data initial_data.json then i removed it but i keep getting this error when i try to syncdb even without any initial data.

```
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py, line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint auth_permission_content_type_id_key
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748180/local-postgres-db-keeps-giving-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constra

Comment: no actually i still don't know the problem i have class Meta in my model and method to add some permissions manually i'm not sure if it's causing the problem, but why doesn't this happen with SQLite !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually after looking i found that i have a permission i added customly that propably caused a conflict when i removed it it worked !!